# Connect to wifi via bash script in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, wifi-configuration

This command seems to be kinda outdated because it only supports wep:

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid WIFI_NETWORK key s:WIFI_PASSWORD 
dhclient wlan0
```

I found an alternative way that supports wpa2, but it involved changing a .conf file.
I want really to connect to wifi networks just by running the script. :(

Comment: Look at `wpa_cli`.

Answer (score 0):

I built a quick shell script that does the necessary configuration for connecting to a WiFi network with WPA2 from Debian.

https://gist.github.com/rjsteinert/4999792f4a7aedd532b2

```
#!/bin/sh
## A simple `wifi` command for Debian that will connect you to a WPA2 WiFi network
## usage:
## sudo ./wpa2-wifi-connect.sh <ssid> <pass>

ifdown wlan0

# build the interfaces file that will point to the file that holds our configuration
rm /etc/network/interfaces
touch /etc/network/interfaces
echo 'auto lo' >> /etc/network/interfaces
echo 'iface lo inet loopback' >> /etc/network/interfaces
echo 'iface eth0 inet dhcp' >> /etc/network/interfaces
echo 'allow-hotplug wlan0' >> /etc/network/interfaces
echo 'iface wlan0 inet manual' >> /etc/network/interfaces
echo 'wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf' >> /etc/network/interfaces
echo 'iface default inet dhcp' >> /etc/network/interfaces

# build the supplicant file that holds our configuration
rm /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
touch /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
echo 'ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev' >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
echo 'update_config=1' >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
wpa_passphrase $1 $2 >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

ifup wlan0
```

Comment: As the script is not very long, please include it directly in your answer. That way, if the link goes dead as time goes on, your answer would still hold all the necessary details of the solution.